# Spring cannot construct instance of Interface model

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, interface, model

Currently trying to make a product collect of data, that is to house products of three different categories within a spring mvc api. Ive made 4 model.java; 3 for storing unique data that corresponds to each of these type. And a Fourth which houses all common attributes.  Finally ive made a model interface which is used to decide which model is to be used depending on the operation.

However while im creating my Create method. Im stumbling upon a "Cannot construct instance of interface" error.

Abstract Model

```
 public abstract class AbstractProduct implements Product {
 @Getter private String productId;    
  @Getter @Setter private String productName;
  @Getter @Setter private String duration;
  @Getter @Setter private String productType;
  @Getter @Setter private String productDescription;
  @Getter @Setter private Calendar startDate;
  @Getter @Setter private Calendar endDate; 

  public AbstractProduct(){
  }
  public AbstractProduct (final String productId,final String name, final String duration, final String type,
                          final String description, final Calendar startDate, final Calendar endDate) {

    this.productId = productId;
    this.productName = name;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.productType = type;
    this.productDescription = description;
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
  }
}
```

Product Model

```
public class SubscriptionProduct extends AbstractProduct implements Product{
  @Getter @Setter private String subscriptionType;
  @Getter @Setter private String renewelProductId;

       public SubscriptionProduct(){}
 @Builder
 public SubscriptionProduct (final String productId, final String name, final String duration,
                             final String description, final Calendar startDate, final Calendar endDate,
                             final String subscriptionType,final String renewlProductId) {

    super(productId, name, duration, "SUBSCRIPTION", description, startDate, endDate);     
    this.subscriptionType = subscriptionType;
    this.renewelProductId = renewlProductId;
 }
}
```

Product model interface:

```
public interface Product {
}
```

I can see where the Issue is and im pretty sure its within the controller. However im kinda unsure how to fix this to allow the Product Interface to work as intended.

Controller:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "create", method = RequestMethod.POST)

 public ResponseEntity<Product> create (@RequestBody final Product data) {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Product result = null;

HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.OK;

try {
  result = service.createProduct(data);
}catch(Exception e) {
  status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
}
if (result != null) {
return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
return new ResponseEntity<>(result, status);
}
```

Is there anyway to fix this issue I am having?

Edit 1: heres my service implementation class:

```
  public Product createProduct(Product data) throws ProductException {
     Product result = null;

 ParameterCheckTool.check(new int[]{ParameterCheckTool.CHECK_TYPE_NULL},
        new Object[]{data},
        new String[]{"data"},
        true,
        "createProduct",
        HostProductService.class);

 checkIfServiceIsRunning(this);
 ProductServiceHandler handler = findHandler("");

 if (handler == null) {
 throw new ProductException("No handler found");
 }
 result = handler.createProduct(data);
 return result;
 } 

private ProductServiceHandler findHandler(String request) {
    //Apply Logic here for selecting Handlers.
  return handlers.get("TestHandler");
  }
```

Please ignore the poor indenting, im not too good at it on stack.

Comment: Can you provide the implementation of service.createProduct(data) ?

Comment: Sadly I’ve just left work, but to give a brief explanation of what the service implementation would do would be: continues to use the product interface to chose the right model to use; finds a handler to use and send the data to the handler.  I’ve currently not got a working handler that connects to an endpoint so I’ve also just made a mock handler that would basically send the data back; again referencing the product interface back to the controller as a response.

Comment: Ive now added the service implementation class to the post, hope this provides enough details.

Answer (score -1):

In your controller there is a line that tries to create an instance of this interface, Product, and it should be removed:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "create", method = RequestMethod.POST)

 public ResponseEntity<Product> create (@RequestBody final Product data) {
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Product result = null;              //Remove this line!!
```

Comment: Generally, Java does not allow instantiating interfaces.

Comment: hmm, ill give it a try tomorrow once i get ahold of my work laptopn, thanks for the input! hopefully this solves it

Comment: Hey there, ive done as you've advised and it seems to still give the same error. could it be the fact that im requesting for the data to be input'ed to be in the form of Product within the controller?

Comment: `public ResponseEntity<Product> create (@RequestBody final Product data) ` you cannot use interfaces as a returning objects nor can you pass them parameter.

Comment: Remove the Product interface. It does not have ann implementation anyway.

Comment: You should use `SubscriptionProduct` for all your needs.